# Free software license that does not require to distribute source?

Tags: licensing

Is there any free software license that i don't have to provide source code with

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSD licenses and similar ones have what you need:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses

Check Apache License too:

- http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would like to use a freeware license:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware

You find a list of different licenses to choose from under:

http://www.opensource.org/licenses/category

Answer (score 0):

The BSD license, but the whole point of using an open source licensing scheme is to publish your source code.

If you don't want to publish your source code, what will an open source license buy you that a typical copyright doesn't already do?

Comment: Well maybe he doesn't want to license his software with an open source one, but include open sourced libraries inside his software solution and these must allow him to publish in a commercial and closed source product.